# Setting width of statement columns in bipolar matrix qualtrics

Tags: css, matrix, qualtrics

I am adding a Matrix Table, of bipolar type, in Qualtrics.

I have 3 statements on the left-hand side of the Table, and again 3 statements on the right-hand side, with 2 scale points in the middle.

I would like to adjust the width of the left-hand column and of the right-hand column of the Matrix Table.

What is the code to use?

I have found similar codes in CSS for other types of questions, such as the one below, but nothing for a bipolar matrix table.

```
<style> 
.Skin .SBS .Short { 
width:50px; 
} 
</style>
```

What would be the code to adjust width in bipolar matrix table?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. Strangely, AnswerRight is the left side (right aligned) and AnswerLeft is the right side (left aligned).  The default for both is 50%

```
.Skin .Matrix .Bipolar th.AnswerRight {width:50%}
.Skin .Matrix .Bipolar th.AnswerLeft {width:50%}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to increase the overall width of the bipolar matrix? I have tried changing the % but it still breaks one of the statements (left or right) into two. I can decrease font size, but making matrix wider would be great.

Comment: The matrix (table) is limited by the size of the theme you are using (it is 100% of the available width). So, you can't really increase the matrix size without changing the width of the theme.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification! How could I change the width of the theme?

Comment: You can increase the max-width of the SkinInner class (e.g., `.Skin .SkinInner {max-width:1024px}`)  It may throw off some other things like placement of logos in the header.  To change it for just the page with the bipolar add a `<style>` tag to your question.  To change it for the whole survey, add it to Custom CSS.